# How does SE handle edits by company representatives on questions about their technology which go beyond improvement?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I have recently achieved edit review privileges and have tried to follow agreed edit review practices by looking around SO.meta if I have a question about something.

Today I have seen quite a few questions about IBM's Bluemix technology coming through the edit queue. Many of the proposed edits were from [one user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3198917/bill-wentworth). Their account reads:

> I am the Community/Knowledge Manager and Social Media Specialist for IBM Bluemix Support.

I looked at [their edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3198917/bill-wentworth?tab=activity) after a few edits in the same vein and see that all this user's edits are based around Bluemix. This is unsurprising, but there are a few edits which seem to be made in order to serve IBM's ends, instead of the Stack Overflow community.

For example [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45920975/2):

> removed the " (good to check the number of recognized entities in the user input beforehand)" as I didn't think the sarcasm was good representing IBM.

Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45761790/2):

> I added the containers and the containers-registry tags because they are followed by the IBM teams for these questions

How does SE feel/handle edits made by people who are clearly interested in promoting a technology and are paid by that technology (even if most of their edits on the topic are improvements)?

Comment: I pinged the editor and prompted them to this question

Comment: The only thing IBM's "Social media specialists" have succeeded in for me is convincing me that Bluemix is an ecosystem I never want to go near. And I realised that a long time before this question.

Comment: IBM is a large corporation and the services that are provided on the Bluemix platform come from teams all over the world. To ensure that subject matter experts within the company are alerted to questions from our customers, we have use specific tags. If those tags are not used in those questions, our teams will not be alerted. I don't feel that adding the containers and container-registry tags for something clearly involving that topic is an incorrect edit.

Comment: @BillWentworth while I cannot say in this case, as I have no knowledge on the question, SO guidance says *Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains.* Please keep that in mind.

Comment: @CalvT븃 Understood. I just don't understand the issue with adding tags that help people find the information now and in the future. We're here to get community members the answers that they need. I don't like making an edit just for tags, but if it is needed, it is needed. Can SE consider another approach, perhaps, when we are just adding tags rather than adding it to the Edit queue?

Comment: It seems to me that the containers tag looks an awful lot like a meta tag in general anyway - it fails the burnination criteria [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/271280).

Comment: @Ajean For questions about the Containers and Containers Registry technology on our platform, what tags do you suggest? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @BillWentworth I can't comment on containers-registry, and I have zero knowledge of your framework, but if you look at the tag wiki for containers it's just an overly broad tag that is not specific to your platform, it's about *any* container in *any* platform in *any* language, which is hardly helpful.

Comment: @Ajean, a meta tag describes the question itself, not the question's subject. [containers] is not a meta tag.

Comment: @Ajean Correct, which is why we combine the tag usage with [ibm-bluemix]. Thus, for a question about the Containers service on Bluemix, you should always see [ibm-bluemix] and [containers] together. We try to reuse tags when they make sense and create new ones for services when something close does not exist. We also want to make sure that the tags we choose would be easily identifiable with the service.

Comment: @JoshCaswell The issue here is that the tag is being used in a way that's contrary to its definition.  It's being used as, "any question that the IBM corporation should look at" rather than, "any question that's actually about topic X".  Thus the practice of adding a tag that doesn't apply to the question, just to get IBM people to see it, is *treating* the tag as a meta-tag.  Of course, the problem here is that usage, not the tag itself (assuming the tag does have a sensible topic that it can actually represent).

Comment: ... a bigger problem is that someone is trying to make SO their entitled support platform. SO absolutely does not have to abide by any requirement IBM, or said user, can have. Users don't get to demand from SO to manage their own case separately from anyone else.

Comment: SO is definitely NOT considered an entitled support platform by IBM Bluemix. It is an option to get help from other peoples' experience. If someone needs to open a Bluemix Support ticket based on their account specifications, they can do it. We add tags to questions to identify the subject to which it pertains, which makes it easier for community members, customers, and IBMers. Like any other company, such as Amazon, Microsoft, Cisco, and so on, we have a variety of people here helping others with their questions. I don't believe we work with SO any differently than other companies.

Comment: @JoshCaswell You're probably right about that, I threw the term out rather loosely. Although a quick perusal through the front page of [containers] does not inspire confidence that it's really doing any good to its questions - some of them involve things with actual Containers like docker or ibm-bluemix, and some are just python or c++ questions tangentially related to containing *something*.  What do you call a tag that is so overly broad like that? (Real question, not facetious). Maybe it just needs trimming?

Comment: ... or possibly a tag wiki edit?

Comment: @Ajean: Yes, it could very well be a overly-broad, non-specific tag that needs to be removed. I don't know that we have a specific term for them: "useless", I guess.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Generally speaking if the edit is an improvement then it doesn't matter that the editor works with the technology.

However, I disagree with the first example that removed:

> (good to check the number of recognized entities in the user input beforehand).

I don't see how it reads as sarcastic and I'm not surprised that the OP added this back into their answer after two reviewers approved it. In any case,

> didn't think the sarcasm was good representing IBM.

is not a legitimate reason for editing something out. If it was a rant it could be removed as noise but we don't remove content just because a company thinks it makes them look bad.

Similarly, the second edit appears to have added an irrelevant tag. IBM teams may be following the [containers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/containers/info) tag but that tag is neither specific to IBM nor does it appear to be what the question is about.

Comment: This. Domain experts improving answers is *great*; we want to encourage that. People making contestable edits, especially for political/marketing reasons, is unacceptable and is to be sharply discouraged.

Comment: I am the Knowledge Manager for the Bluemix Platform here at IBM and my profile is upfront about that position. The post in question was from a fellow IBMer and, thus, I believe that I have full authority to determine what should be published by someone representing IBM.

Comment: @BillWentworth when your fellow IBMer posted that, they licensed it to SE, so no, it's actually SE that has the authority to decide what is in the post.

Comment: Your authority inside your company is just that, it does not extend to StackOverflow. If you would like to change something posted by a member of your company then I think speaking to them would be a better method, rather than potentially misusing the edit system.

Comment: How is it a misuse of the edit system?

Comment: In terms of the snarky comment, I will agree not to handle it through edits to a post and handle it internally.

Comment: Tagging, on the other hand, is vital to helping our customers.

Comment: _"vital to helping our customers"_ Well, you can tag things however you like on your own website.

Comment: The community polices this site. We are a partner and a contributor like any other company. We want our customers and community members to find the information that they need to solve their problems. The previous comment was a matter of semantics.

Comment: All - You raise some valid points and given me food for thought. Going forward, I will exercise more caution when suggesting textual edits and make doubly certain the main goal of the edit is improving the content for the SO community. We're all here to help each other regardless of who we work for.

Comment: @Bill thanks for being receptive to the community concerns - it's most appreciated.

Comment: @Bill Just a suggestion, as previously mentioned the tags you're using for "monitoring" are rather ambiguous, and not at all specifc to bluemix/IBM. Maybe pick a more specific tag to follow, in which case adding it to questions where it may increase the likelihood of the question receiving a good answer would be absolutely appropriate (so long as the tag is appropriate).

Answer (score -5):

In my opinion users that do this should be review banned because it seems like a misuse of the system.

As already mentioned in the comments and @BSMP's answer, the company users don't have any authority to edit whatever they feel like because it may or may not make their company look bad.

Also I don't think most of these edits are improvements. Re-tagging or adding tags to "help company developers find these issues" is not helping SO users. Looking through the first page of the edits, in this case, shows that only some actually have answers and very few have accepted answers. What is the point of following these questions without answering them? I suspect that there is a reason, otherwise IBM would not spend developers time (ie money) on this, and these questions are used somewhere.

Comment: To be fair, adding tags that will increase a question's likelihood of receiving an answer is an accepted form of editing. Just like if someone has a question about handling images in JavaScript and they've only included he image tag, adding javascript _would be appropriate.

Comment: @TinyGiant I completely agree with your point but in this case all these changes don't seem to be done to increase that likelihood